# Exporting Class with Require yields error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class

There is a nuance that I seem to be missing. I have Googled so many fixes recommended for this problem I don't know what is real anymore, nothing seems to work.

[MyProject](https://replit.com/@GeorgeSchafer/Class-Extends-Error#libs/ReplitDB.js) on Replit and the offending class I am trying to export.

I keep getting the same error. I have commented out other changes I have tried in my effort. I want to cut the Gordian knot and just paste the ReplitDB class into my MoodDB class, but I also want to understand what I am missing here.

**Offending lines:**

*ReplitDB.js - Method A*

```
...
exports.module = ReplitDB;
```

*ReplitDB.js - Method B*

```
modules.export = ReplitDB ;
```

*returns:*

```
ReferenceError: modules is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Class-Extends-Error/libs/ReplitDB.js:110:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Class-Extends-Error/libs/MoodDB.js:23:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
```

*MoodDB.js:*

```
const ReplitDB = require('./ReplitDB.js')

class MoodDB extends ReplitDB {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    
    ...
}
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Class-Extends-Error/libs/MoodDB.js:7:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Class-Extends-Error/index.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
```

Comment: Can you show how you export your class in the ReplitDB.js file ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit

Well now I feel rather silly. It worked. I saw so many variations of module(s).export(s) I forgot what it was supposed to be. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your export. It should be

```js
module.exports = ReplitDB;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw so many variations on module(s) and export(s) I forgot the correct syntax. #fail

Comment: @TheJadedGeorge you can think about it in terms of "in that module, these are the exports", you are defining one or more exports for this single module.

Comment: That's brilliant!